# Spring and Compression

Tags: spring

A 5.00 x 10^5 kg subway train is brought to a stop from a speed of 0.500 m/s in 0.400 m by a large spring bumper at the end of its track. What is the force constant k of the spring?

Okay so I know you use 0.5 times k times x squared to find potential energy of a spring, but here this problem is giving me mass, and displacement...? Also I still don't really understand what x is (I know its the amount of compression) but how to you spot it in a question? 
Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, I think they want us to take $0.4 m$ as the displacement from the relaxed state of the spring.

We take $x=0.4m$ and then apply energy conservation principle.

Thus,
$$1/2mv^2=1/2kx^2$$
$$= 1/2\times5\times10^-5\times1/4=1/2k\times 16/100$$

Solving this, we get:

$K= \frac{5}{10} \times 10^{-3}$